# unchecked only all child node in treeview

Tags: c#, treeview, treenode, checked, unchecked

I'm using treeview , and I use from this code form checked and unchecked all Child Node when select parent or child node

```
private bool updatingTreeView;
private void CheckChildren_ParentSelected(TreeNode node, Boolean isChecked)
{
    foreach (TreeNode item in node.Nodes)
    {
        item.Checked = isChecked;

        if (item.Nodes.Count > 0)
        {
            this.CheckChildren_ParentSelected(item, isChecked);
        }
    }
}
private void SelectParents(TreeNode node, Boolean isChecked)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(node.Parent.ToString());
    if (node.Parent != null)
    {
        node.Parent.Checked = isChecked;
        SelectParents(node.Parent, isChecked);
    }
}
private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (updatingTreeView) return;
    updatingTreeView = true;
    CheckChildren_ParentSelected(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
    SelectParents(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
    updatingTreeView = false;
}
```

But now

here is the problem :

when I unchecked child node i want only unchecked all childnode in treeview.

like this picture :

[image: nchecked all childnode]

**But with my code all parent and child (both) is unchecked !!!**

so now i want to know how can I unchecked only all child node in treeview ,

now how to change this code for fix this problem ?

Kind Regards.

Comment: In your example how would you ever uncheck node 6? Seems that if you only clear the root nodes, you won't ever be able to clear the root

Comment: @timmy : I don't know that i possible with my code or now but I know that is possible :D so do you have any idea for me ? :(

Comment: For me it looks like SelectParents is recursively un-checking all paretnts till node.Parent is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"when I unchecked child node i want only unchecked all childnode in treeview."

In other words, you don't want to **uncheck** parent nodes?

In that case, only call SelectParents() when a node is selected:

```
private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (updatingTreeView) return;
    updatingTreeView = true;
    CheckChildren_ParentSelected(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
    if (e.Node.Checked)
    {
        SelectParents(e.Node, e.Node.Checked);
    }
    updatingTreeView = false;
}
```